# Esc/P for setting page length in inch

Tags: php, printing, epson, dot-matrix

I need to set up ESC/P for page length in PHP which is 5.5 inch.  My printer is LX300+ and the code is:

```
$page_length = Chr(27) . Chr(67) . Chr(0) . "5.5";
```

Is that correct way for Esc C 0 n (n=5.5).  Does not seems to work right.  Is there any way to put 5.5 in Chr()?

Should I set the printing page length in the printer itself or in the windows driver is enough?  Thx!

Answer (score 0):

Seems that setting page length by inch only works if increment is 1.  I use set page length by line instead.  Case close.

Comment: Hi @Anakin, how you are setting page, please provide some info. Please give some idea. I am using php5.4.

Comment: @DineshPatra: Page length using line: $page_length = Chr(27) . Chr(67) . "line-number";